# Dynamically generating JSX in React

Tags: javascript, dynamic, reactjs, jsx

I want to generate options from an array for a select form. This is inside a React component's render method and being transpiled with JSX.

```
render: function(){
    return(
        <div className="control-group">
            <select id="select-food" placeholder="Pick a food...">
                <option value="">select a food</option>
                {Object.keys(this.state.foods).forEach((food) => {
                    return (<option value={food}>{food}</option>);
                })}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I can output the foods inside the `forEach` loop to the console with `console.log()` just fine, but the HTML just isn't getting generated. What am I missing here to get it to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot return from inside a `forEach` loop. You'll want to use `.map()` instead, which will return a new array. More info about `map` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="control-group">
      <select id="select-food" placeholder="Pick a food...">
        <option value="">select a food</option>
        {Object.keys(this.state.foods).map((food) => {
          return (<option value={food}>{food}</option>);
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use map or helper function check link https://egghead.io/lessons/react-dynamically-generated-components. good place to start

```js
render: function(){
let options = ['book', 'cat', 'dog'];

    return(
        <div className="control-group">
            <select id="select-food" placeholder="Pick a food...">
               {options.map(food => <option key={id} value={food}>{food}</option>)}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

another solution in my demo

```js
renderRepository() {
let repository = this.props.repositories.find((repo)=>repo.name === this.props.params.
repo_name);
let stars = [];
for (var i = 0; i < repository.stargazers_count; i++) {
stars.push('');
}
return(
<div>
<h2>{repository.name}</h2>
<p>{repository.description}</p>
<span>{stars}</span>
</div>
);
}
render() {
if(this.props.repositories.length > 0 ){
return this.renderRepository();
} else {
return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
}
}
}
```